# match everything after regex not including regex

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the regex for matching everything after `Call\s+\Me` ? So everything after `Call` any amount of whitespace then `Me` ignoring case?

Comment: Do you have any specific language in mind?

Comment: @thefourtheye javascript

Comment: `everything after Call\s+\Me` **is not same as** `everything after Call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capturing group like this

```
console.log(/Call\s+Me(.*)/i.exec("Call me if possible"));
```

This will give you the following

```
[ 'Call me if possible',
  ' if possible',
  index: 0,
  input: 'Call me if possible' ]
```

Here, the first item is the actual string which got matched in the entire string, second item in the array is what we want.